# $.getJSON not firing console.log

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been facing some weird situation in my jQuery $.getJSON event. I'm able to see the JSON response on my console i.e. the file is getting called but console.log does not seem to work.

Here is the code that I'm writing:

```
$.getJSON("response.json",function(data){
                console.log(data);
});
```

I tried using single quotes as well but it does not seem to work. This was perfectly working a few days back and now when I tried to add a new function I'm not able to.

I don't know why this error is popping up and I also changed the double quotes to single quotes but that is not solving the problem.

I tried console.log outside the site

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: add a fail handler and see whether that is getting called

Comment: I'm confused.  You say "I'm able to see the JSON response on my console" -- How did it get there?  Isn't that what `console.log` _does_?

Comment: `$.getJSON("response.json", function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}).fail(function (jqxhr, status, error) {
    console.log('error', status, error)
});`

Comment: Sorry my bad. There was some error in the JSON data. Since it was a very huge JSON data, I could not see it manually. Found out after the error was logged and then realized that there was a quote missing on one line. Anyway thanks you @ArunPJohny.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.getJSON("response.json", function (data) { 
console.log(data); 
})
.fail(function (jqxhr, status, error) { 
console.log('error', status, error) }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be one possibilities of failure of getJson call that your json file is not in correct format as according to jquery ajax if json is not in proper format then that service will fail.
You can check it with below code :

```js
var jqxhr = $.getJSON( "response.json", function(data) {
 console.log( "success : " + data);
}).fail(function(jqxhr, tatus, error) {
 console.log( "error :" + error );
}).always(function() {
 console.log( "complete" );
});
```